# How to prove that a certain payment has been made by a certain user?

Tags: transactions, addresses, signature, private-key

I have a website in the beta stage, on which users will be able to pay by crypto. **Out of simplicity and for now**, I want to use a single address and verify the payments manually because there won't be many users for now.

How could a user prove that a certain transaction has come from him as he claims? That is, to avoid a situation when a user is trying to assing someone else's payment to himself.

A screenshot of his wallet can be forged - can't be a proof.

I've heard about asking a user to sign a message. How will it work? And what message - any string whatsoever or some special one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask the user to connect to your website via Web3, using something like the web3js or ethers libraries, you will be able to see which wallet he's connected with. Then you can query his wallet address with your address list.

Additionally,

- you can create a smart contract that will save whoever sent the contract payment. Then, your website can query the smart contract to check whether the user's address has paid. This will save you some manual work.
- Signing: yeah, the message is quite arbitrary. You can ask the user to sign for example "I approve that I am the owner of this address" and then decode the message to verify it was signed from the correct address. But AFAIS ATM this doesn't really make it easier for anybody, as the user still will need to sign into his own wallet - and at that point you already know that's him.

Comment: `But AFAIS ATM this doesn't really make it easier for anybody, as the user still will need to sign into his own wallet - and at that point you already know that's him.` --> how do I know this?

Comment: `If you ask the user to connect to your website via Web3, using something like the web3js or ethers libraries, you will be able to see which wallet he's connected with. Then you can query his wallet address with your address list.` --> 1) and if I don't? 2) what's "your address list"?

Comment: You can try building a simple dapp to see what I mean. When a user for example connects his MetaMask wallet to your website, you are able to see which address he is connected with. So you can identify him. Regarding "address list", I meant the list of addresses that have paid.

Comment: But why do you assume that a user uses MetaMask, though?

Comment: The user has to use some web3 wallet like MM or Coinbase Wallet. MM is just an example. This is how it's usually done in the web3 world - users connect their wallet to your website and then you can identify them and ask them to sign transactions. If a user pays you straight out of his CEX account (like Binance account), you don't have a way to verify the payment came from him.

Comment: `The user has to use some web3 wallet like MM or Coinbase Wallet.` -- user doesn't have to. He can use any desktop wallet, any mobile one, or even code in Python with a private key in a text file